Swagger cannot resolve exist ref
I used go-swagno to generate swagger docs and faced with this issue:

In my code I use generic struct listResponseDto to describe response with items and count fields:
type listResponseDto[D any] struct {
    Count int64 `json:"count"`
    Items []D   `json:"items"`
}

My playersResponse struct:
type playersResponse struct {
    Result bool                             `json:"result" example:"true"`
    Data   listResponseDto[entities.Player] `json:"data"`
}

In doc.json file everything look like correct. This is endpoint json:

Then controllers.playersResponse:

And finally listResponseDto:

Why swagger cannot resolve pointer?
